# Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o programa "curl" imprima pausadamente as informações na tela?

Tags: windows, libcurl, cmd, terminal

Por exemplo, quando chamo o menu de ajuda no terminal CMD do Windows, "curl --help", vem uma chuva de informações na tela, ficando bem ruim de acompanhar a leitura.

Answer (score 1):

Em terminais geralmente o "pause" funciona bem, mas é um tanto quanto complicado pausar no ponto desejado, cada terminal tem suas caracterizaras, geralmente sistemas visuais veem com "emuladores de terminal" o que permite usar o scrollbar, o mesmo vale para o CMD, "basta rolar" de volta.

Mas para facilitar você pode salvar em um documento usando `>`, por exemplo:

```
curl --help > curl.txt
```

E ler no seu editor de textos favoritos, ou então ler em https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

---

Nessa postagem no SOen deram uma série de sugestões:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/15255070/1518921

Algumas sugestões que pareceram interessante:

Usar o comando `less` (creio não ser algo padrão em todos sistemas, mas não posso afirmar):

```
curl --help | less
```

Depois é só usar a seta para cima e baixo.

A outra sugestão foi usar a tecla <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> (<kbd>ScrLk</kbd>) antes de executar o comando para então depois poder controlar com <kbd>PageUp</kbd> (<kbd>PgUp</kbd>) e <kbd>PageDown</kbd> (<kbd>PgDn</kbd>) , mas não tenho certeza do comportamento em diferentes terminais/sistemas e ainda não tive a oportunidade de testar.

Comment: Agradeço pela atenção, Guilherme!
O comando  "pipe" less eu já conheço, utilizo no linux, e é exatamente esse mesmo comportamento que eu procuro para utilizar no curl. Mas a documentação do curl é bem extensa e a navegação pelo notebook no CMD é terrível, então achei melhor perguntar aqui direto a quem utiliza a ferramenta com mais frequência. Grato pelas informações.

Comment: @ElcioAugustoDalosto sendo windows (cmd), o `curl --help > curl.txt` não resolveu?

Comment: Esse comando aí seria pra salvar os dados em um arquivo .txt, mas a minha intenção é usar apenas o terminal para ler as instruções de forma rápida, apenas para consultar os comandos, pra não precisar lidar muito com o mouse ou ficar catando arquivos nas pastas manualmente. De qualquer forma se eu fosse ler o .txt salvo ele abriria na tela uma "tripa" enorme de informações que ficaria ruim de ler da mesma forma.

Comment: Esse comando aí seria pra salvar os dados em um arquivo .txt, mas a minha intenção é usar apenas o terminal para ler as instruções de forma rápida, apenas para consultar os comandos, pra não precisar lidar muito com o mouse ou ficar catando arquivos nas pastas manualmente. De qualquer forma se eu fosse ler o .txt salvo ele abriria na tela uma "tripa" enorme de informações que ficaria ruim de ler da mesma forma.

Comment: @ElcioAugustoDalosto sendo windows não vejo dificuldades nisto ou em ler a doc https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html, eu mesmo tenho uma série de "txts" com instruções rapidas e "snippets" (exemplos de comandos que uso muito para eu copiar rapido).

Comment: Sim, é uma forma de se realizar a leitura, mas eu procurava exatamente o que o amigo do comentário abaixo mandou. Seria o curl --help | more, que permite ler o texto chamado pausadamente, sendo rolado ao apertar alguma tecla. O comando | less não funciona no cmd, acho q só em terminal linux ou se baixar a lib pro cmd. O estranho é que no help do curl nao fala nada sobre usar o comando "pipe" more pra listar com pausa. Enfim, foi resolvido, te agradeço mesmo assim.

Comment: @ElcioAugustoDalosto pipe não tem haver com o curl, o curl é um programa, o pipe é um controle de input (e output) do terminal para os comandos, semelhante a uma condição.

Answer (score 1):

---

> - Fica a sugestão de conhecer o **unxutils**, trata-se de alguns executáveis do linux já portados para a plataforma Windows, inclusive o <kbd>**`less`**</kbd>
> - **<kbd>`curl --help | less.exe`</kbd>**
> - O **unxutils** está disponível nesse site:   ****<kbd>[`http://unxutils.sourceforge.net`](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net)</kbd>****

---

> - Alternativa não muito cheia de recursos como o **<kbd>`less.exe`</kbd>**, seria usar o **<kbd>**`more`**</kbd>** :

---

---

```
curl --help | more
```

Ou ainda, capturar a saída (crtl+c) via clip:

```
curl --help | clip & curl --help | more
```

Ainda tens a opção de abrir a saída movida para texto (presente na resposta do @guilhermenascimento):

```
>"%temp%\curl_help.txt" curl.exe --help && "%temp%\curl_help.txt"
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso o o que eu procurava! Grato, meu amigo 

Comment: O pipe e o more são do Windows, pipe eh um operador e more um sofrer que vem junto do Windows e aceita redirecionamento do operador.